# Browser extension (or other software) to delay page load

Tags: browser, browser-addons, productivity

The alt text to [today's comic at xkcd.com](http://xkcd.com/862/) (strip below) says:

> After years of trying, I broke this
>   habit in a day by decoupling the
>   action and the neurological reward. **I set up a simple 30-second delay I had to wait through, in which I couldn't do anything else, before any new page or chat client would load**
>    (and only
>   allowed one to run at once). The urge
>   to check all those sites magically
>   vanished--and my 'productive' computer
>   use was unaffected.

(bold is my emphasis)

Does anybody know of a browser extension or other software that will add this sort of delay? I've seen extensions which simply block sites, but not a delay like this.

Comment: A similar question on a StackExchange site that is better suited for product recommendations: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17442/chrome-extension-to-delay-web-page-loading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [Delayed Gratification](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/eacjcpfjdlcdggndfhkmlpnhedggdhke)

> Inspired by XKCD, this extension
>   allows you to add a 30-second delay to
>   the loading of websites you specify.
>   This delayed gratification is a small
>   roadbump that removes the instant
>   reward of going to time-wasting
>   websites, while still allowing you to
>   get to them.

Comment: This doesn't reset the timer when you switch away from the tab during the count-down, which is important. This other extension gets it right: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nbgjmohekjolcgemlolblankocjlgalf#

Comment: This extension seems to work on a page-by-page basis, not for an entire site.

Comment: That link is dead, but there's an extension by that name at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/delayed-gratification/ifhndomfnbmggdgodaicfebeggdphlcn

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Chrome, try the [Crackbook](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nbgjmohekjolcgemlolblankocjlgalf) extension.

Comment: The original extension by this name is gone, but it looks like there's an active fork: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crackbook-revival/fakedinbmdjifniaepnfbplcheaecebc

Answer (score 2):

Keep an eye on the comments on [Randall's blog post](http://blog.xkcd.com/2011/02/18/distraction-affliction-correction-extensio/) on this topic. There is already a link to a [proxy implementation in ruby](http://www.reddit.com/tb/fo276) which delays the loading of certain sites.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented an extension after reading this comic but never advertised it. Check it out [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nabnopkhfcpmemafeophjpjacpofpdbb)

Comment: This looks to no longer be online.